# Webservice Calling in Sleep mode

Tags: android

I would like to run webservice in sleep mode in my app is it possible?
please suggest any ideas or reference codes.

Comment: Look into Android services...

Comment: I used Schedulers,Timers, Alarm Managers but in sleep mode webservice not calling ..Once I wake up screen then servicing calling working fine in that case.but I would like to run webservice in sleep mode how???????

Comment: Service in sleep mode, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942622/how-to-make-service-run-even-in-sleep-mode

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `AlarmManager` in a [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)